# How do you handle conditional html formating?

Tags: html, django

In one of my html pages I have the following:

```
{% for bet in recent_bets %}
    {% if bet.status__name == "Won" or bet.status__name == "Half Won"%}
        <div class="container col recent-form_col bg-success"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{{ bet.date }}, {{ bet.time }}">
    {% elif bet.status__name == "Lost" or bet.status__name == "Half Lost"%}
        <div class="container col recent-form_col bg-danger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{{ bet.status }}">
    {% elif bet.status__name == "Void" or bet.status__name == "Cancelled"%}
         <div class="container col recent-form_col bg-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{{ bet.status }}">
    {% elif bet.status__name == "Cash Out" %}
        <div class="container col recent-form_col bg-warning" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{{ bet.status }}">
{% endif %}
```

Based on what the `bet.status__name` is, it returns a different background color ex `bg-success`.

Apart from this case, I have a few other cases similar to that.

I would like to know how do you handle these things. Just leave it in the html, create a filter/tag that returns the appropriate html or something else ?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely encapsulate the logic about which kind of status leads to which CSS class. You can create a filter that takes a bet and returns the right CSS class:

```
<div class="container col recent-form_col bg-{{ bet|get_bet_css_class }}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{{ bet.date }}, {{ bet.time }}">
```

This way you can also reuse it with Bootstrap's `alert` component etc.